# GSSAPI on MariaDB

Tags: mariadb, windows-server, mariadb-10.2

I'm using Maria 10.2.13 on Windows Server 2012 and I want to use GSSAPI authentication with it so that we can continue using windows auth.

I have followed this tutorial:
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/authentication-plugin-gssapi/#comment_3261

Im getting the following error when trying to login via ODBC:

```
[ma-3.0.3] Plugin auth_gssapi_client could not be loaded: The specified module 
could not be found
```

I've checked and the plugin_dir is pointing at the right folder. 
    `\MariaDB 10.2\lib\plugin\`

Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 1):

I see in the comments to the MariaDB tutorial page you linked to that you have set plugin_dir in you my.ini file. However, I think this will only work if it's in a section of my.ini that the mysql client can/will read, such as the `[mysql]` section (not `[mysqld]`).

Assuming us1 was created as `IDENTIFIED VIA gssapi` and everything else is correctly configured: Have you tried connecting just with the mysql client?

```
mysql --plugin-dir=/path/to/plugin-dir -u usr1
```

If plugin_dir is in the right section of my.ini, then this should also work:

```
mysql -u usr1
```